# UIActivityViewController animates in a weird way when presented

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am using the following code to present a `UIActivityViewController`:

```
func share(content: Any, from viewController: UIViewController) {
                        
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: ["TEST"],
            applicationActivities: []
        )
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Is there any other specifications you would like to provide?

Comment: Yep, it turned out to be that library https://github.com/icanzilb/EasyAnimation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using [EasyAnimation](https://github.com/icanzilb/EasyAnimation) which advices for enabling it in `AppDelegate`. That was the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all in this extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
func share2(vc: UIViewController, content: Any) {
    let text = "TEST"
    let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```

now call the extension func wherever you want like this:

```
@objc func share() {
    share2(vc: self, content: yourContent) 
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference :(